# API Platform - Changing max_age config value doesn't change the max-age request value

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com, max-age

I have an application with API Platform and an other which consume my API.

I want to change the max-age value but when I change the value in the config, it doesn't change the value when I send a request...

Here is my config:

```
api_platform:
  ...
  http_cache:
    max_age: 600
  ...
```

And here is my request and response headers:
[image: request and response headers]

Tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RFC discusses max-age here: [Header Field Definitions](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3)
Also this page can help you a lot : [Hypertext Transfer Protocol](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)

The possible **`max-age`** value is dependent on **browser/version** and any **proxy** in the way.

It makes sense to apply to cache-control too in the absence of any explicit standards guidance.

It's as long as you should generally need anyway and picking any arbitrarily longer value could break some user-agents.

Comment: Can I change the http-field field value at will? Your links helped me a lot.

Comment: @Kaizen, It is at your disposal. You can change any field value to your own preference. However, you must change it to a value that the server recognizes.

Answer (score 1):

A possible explanation why the response cache headers are set to private and max-age=0 is that there is a session open (even if you don't use it). When that happens, the SessionListener will override the cache headers to disable it.

In order to fix this issue, you then just have to set stateless: true in the configuration of your firewall :

```
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            stateless: true
```